# Java JTabbedPane, update others tab JLabel value?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtabbedpane

I have 2 `JTabbedPane`. I am unable to refresh the data. PLease help, here is my code:

pane1:

```
//.. some codes...
// This is the ButtonListener
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
      userInput = tf.getText(); // tf is JTextField
      //System.out.println("the input is "+ finalInput);
      pane2.updateData(userInput);
    }
}
```

pane2:

```
public void updateData(String s){
    System.out.println("Update data function is called");
    labelUser.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
    labelUser.setText("Updated text here " + s);
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
public static Pane2 p2 = new Pane2();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f= new JFrame ("My Frame");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame .EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
        p2 = new Pane2();

        tp.addTab("Pane1", new PaneFirst(p2));
        tp.addTab("Pane2", new PaneSecond());

        f.add(tp);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

The `labelUser` never updates, but I trace the `updateData` function, its being called.  Why is the text in `labelUser` not being updated?

EDIT:

"`labelUser`" come from `pane2.java` class.

Comment: Please indent the code properly (use four spaces to tell the site "this is code")!

Comment: @Aaron, why can't you do that?

Comment: I don't see where labelUser comes from. Is the widget visible at all?

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. please take a look

Comment: @Justin: I want him to learn to ask properly. [Update] See? It works. :-)

Comment: Anyting not clear, please let me know. My bad

Comment: Where does "labelUser" come from?

Comment: @Aaron, you are correct.  It did work.  I will leave my comment so these comments make sense.

Comment: I will be back in few minutes

Comment: You have to include all relevant code: Pane2, PaneFirst, PaneSecond, etc. There's no psychic here who can debug your code without seeing it.

Comment: Agreed, also people would generally find it easier to debug if you use descriptive names for you panels.

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* Apparently this didn't fix the problem.

One thing to try would be:

```
public void updateData(String s){
    System.out.println("Update data function is called");
    labelUser.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
    labelUser.setText("Updated text here " + s);
    repaint(); // add this line to tell your pane to repaint itself
}
```

There is a chance that your panel is just not getting repainted.

Comment: `setText()` should force a repaint eventually :-/

Comment: For more logging, add "s" to your System.out.println:
System.out.println("Update data function is called with text: " + s);

And debug.

Comment: @web_starter - could you show us the code where the second pane is created? Or just double-check that you *really* add `labelUser` to the pane and don't have something like `pane.add(new Label("test"));`

Comment: Like Andreas, I think you are updating the wrong label. Probably it is not the one added to pane2.

Comment: I can 100% assure, I updating the correct label, why? I do a test, i create a button in pane2, when triggered I call the same function updateData(), its update my labelUser. I amvery, very very sure, I am updating the correct label.. =(

Comment: @web, so the label updates when the button is pressed from the same pane as the label, it updates, but when the button is pressed from a different pane, it doesn't update?

Comment: yes sire justin. I have been fixing this for 2 days, search through the web, no solution...= (

Comment: Could you post your whole code for both panes and main method somewhere and link here? This is getting more and more interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a typo but - in `actionPerformed()` you store the content of the textfield in `userInput` but use `finalInput` to update pane2.

Comment: Its not typo. If typo, I wont go through the compiler, I will edit the question, change the finalInout to userInput